# dplyr: ifelse with times in R - need option to return NULL, 0 or NA

Tags: r, if-statement, time, dplyr

Need some help with this code. It seems  that the problem is in the TRUE condition in which I intend to indicate that it is NULL. I've already tested several alternatives but I couldn't find a solution.

```
library(lubridate)
library(hms)
df1              <- Sample1 %>%
                    mutate(Start_day = format(StartSession,format = "%d"),
                           End_day = format(EndSession,format ="%d"),
                           Dif_days = if_else (Start_day == End_day,0,1), 
                           StartSession_Time1 = hms::as_hms(StartSession),
                           EndSession_Time1 = if_else(Dif_days == 0, hms::as_hms(EndSession), as_hms("23:59:59")),
                           StartSession_Time2 = if_else(Dif_days == 0, NULL, as_hms("00:00:00")),
                           EndSession_Time2 = if_else(Dif_days == 0, NULL, hms::as_hms(EndSession)))
```

**Error message:**
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `StartSession_Time2`. x `false` must be a logical vector, not a `hms/difftime` object. ?? Input `StartSession_Time2` is `if_else(Dif_days == 0, NA, as_hms("00:00:00"))

Tks in advance

Comment: `NULL` can't be used. Try `as_hms(NA)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NULL` is a 0-length object with `class` "NULL" , so it can't be used as an output to your `if_else()` call, (or base R's `ifelse` for that matter).

You need to match the `hms` class for both the TRUE and FALSE conditions if using `if_else`, like:

```
data.frame(x = 1:10) %>%
   mutate(out = if_else(x > 5, as_hms(NA), as_hms("00:00:00")) )

#    x      out
#1   1 00:00:00
#2   2 00:00:00
#3   3 00:00:00
#4   4 00:00:00
#5   5 00:00:00
#6   6       NA
#7   7       NA
#8   8       NA
#9   9       NA
#10 10       NA
```